# Use all possible levels of a factor to generate zero length() in an output

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I'd like to summarize and count the number of cases within a group and have the output place a zero in a group where no cases exist. For example:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(Station = c("TR1", "TR1", "TR1", "TR1", "TR1", 
                           "TR1", "TR1", "TR1", "TR2", "TR2", "TR2", "TR2", "TR2", "TR2", 
                           "TR2"), Age = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4), 
               WeightTurtles = c(21, 22, 20, 43, 32, 32, 27, 32, 21, 22, 
                                 20, 15, 32, 37, 34)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                 ), row.names = c(NA, -15L), .Names = c("Station", "Age", "WeightTurtles"
                                 ))

df %>%
  group_by(Station, Age) %>%
  summarise(NumTurtles=length(WeightTurtles))
```

Here is the result:

> ```
>   Station   Age NumTurtles
>     (chr) (dbl)      (int)
> 1     TR1     1          3
> 2     TR1     2          2
> 3     TR1     3          1
> 4     TR1     4          2
> 5     TR2     1          4
> 6     TR2     3          1
> 7     TR2     4          2
> ```

What I would like is a row included in the above output that looks like this:

> ```
> 5     TR2     2          0
> ```

So that is, how do I include occurrences (or lack of occurrences as it were) for levels on a factor that have zero length. More generally, how do I tell R to use all possible levels of a factor to count length?

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(df[1:2]))`

Comment: Thank you. Is there any method within a `dplyr` framework?

Comment: ha, idk sorry, I am a bastion for base R ;) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `complete` function from `tidyr`. `complete` adds a row for the missing group and fills `NA` for the value of `WeightTurtles` for that row (unless you choose a different fill value):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  complete(Age, nesting(Station)) %>%
  group_by(Station, Age) %>%
  summarise(NumTurtles=sum(!is.na(WeightTurtles)))
```

> ```
>   Station   Age NumTurtles
> 1     TR1     1          3
> 2     TR1     2          2
> 3     TR1     3          1
> 4     TR1     4          2
> 5     TR2     1          4
> 6     TR2     2          0
> 7     TR2     3          1
> 8     TR2     4          2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution I can think of with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- left_join(expand.grid(Station = unique(df$Station),
                            Age = unique(df$Age), stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                df)
df %>%
  group_by(Station, Age) %>%
  summarise(NumTurtles = sum(!is.na(WeightTurtles)))

Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: Station [?]

  Station   Age NumTurtles
    <chr> <dbl>      <int>
1     TR1     1          3
2     TR1     2          2
3     TR1     3          1
4     TR1     4          2
5     TR2     1          4
6     TR2     2          0
7     TR2     3          1
8     TR2     4          2
```